# Showing that $a \in \text {GL} (A).$

Tags: operator-algebras, banach-algebras

> Let $B$ be a unital Banach algebra and $A$ be a Banach subalgebra of $B$ containing the identity of $B.$ Let $a \in A$ be such that there exists a sequence $\{a_n\}_{n \geq 1}$ in $\text {GL} (A)$ such that $\lim\limits a_n = a.$ If $a \in \text {GL} (B),$ then show that $a \in \text {GL} (A).$

> $\textbf {My Attempt} :$ I am trying to show that $a_n^{-1} \to a^{-1}.$ For that I used the following identity $$a_n^{-1} - a^{-1} = a_{n}^{-1} (a - a_n) a^{-1}.$$ So if we can show that $\{\|a_n^{-1}\|\}_{n \geq 1}$ is a bounded sequence of non-negative real numbers then we are through.

But this is where I got stuck. Any small hint in this regard would be warmly appreciated.

Thanks a bunch.

Comment: You are indeed right that you need to show that this sequence is bounded, and this is true. Little hint: Use that $\|(1-x)^{-1}\| \le \frac{1}{1-\|x\|}$ when $\|x\|< 1$.

Comment: @QuantumSpace you are using Neumann series. Right? But I want to bound $\|a_n^{-1}\|.$ So for that I need to ensure that $\|1 - a_n\| \lt 1$ eventually. Is it obvious?

Comment: Since $a_n \to a$ so $a_n a^{-1} \to 1.$ Hence eventually $\|1 - a_n a^{-1}\| \lt 1.$ Therefore the sequence $\left \{\|a a_n^{-1}\| \right \}_{n \geq 1}$ is bounded above. Will it be needful anyway @QuantumSpace?

Comment: @QuantumSpace I don't get your last comment. You have claimed that the proposed inequality is false and finally come up with the same inequality.

Comment: @QuantumSpace see here $:$ https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Neumann_series

Comment: @QuantumSpace $:$ Since the sequence $\left \{\|a a_n^{-1}\| \right \}_{n \geq 1}$ is bounded above by some $M \gt 0$ it follows that $$\|a_n^{-1}\| = \|a^{-1} (a a_n^{-1})\| \leq \|a ^{-1}\| \|aa_n^{-1}\| \leq M \|a^{-1}\| \lt \infty.$$ Done! Indeed Neumann series did the trick here. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

Since $a$ is invertible, you may assume without loss of generality that $a=1$. So we assume that $a_n\to 1$. Then
\begin{align}
\|1-a_n^{-1}\|&=\|a_n(1-a_n^{-1})+1-a_n^{-1}-a_n(1-a_n^{-1})\|\\[0.3cm]
&=\|(a_n-1) + (1-a_n)(1-a_n^{-1})\|\\[0.3cm]
&\leq\|1-a_n\|+\|1-a_n\|\,\|1-a_n^{-1}\|. 
\end{align}
Regrouping, and as long as $\|1-a_n\|<1$ (which is guaranteed for $n$ big enough),
$$
\|1-a_n^{-1}\|\leq \frac{\|1-a_n\|}{1-\|1-a_n\|}
$$